# Why is call to put() failing to compile in Kotlin when it compiles in Java with similar code

Tags: java, kotlin

I have the following function in java and I need to convert it to Kotlin.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    if (s != null && !"".equals(s.toString())) {
        int position = (Integer) mHolder.numEdit.getTag();
        // Saved to the data variable when the data changes
        mData.get(position).put("list_item_inputvalue",
                s.toString());
    }
}
```

This is the equivalent Kotlin code that I've created:

```
override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

    if (s != null && "" != s.toString()) {
        val position = mHolder.numEdit!!.tag as Int
        // Saved to the data variable when the data changes
        mData?.get(position).put("list_item_inputvalue", s.toString())
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't like the call to `.put()`.  The variable mData in Java is:

```
private List<Map<String, String>> mData;
```

and Kotlin:

```
var mData: List<Map<String, String>>? = null
```

Why doesn't the compiler like the conversion of `put` in Kotlin?

**UPDATE:**

`println(mData) = [{list_item_inputvalue=0}, {list_item_inputvalue=1},...]`

`println(mData?.get(position)) = {list_item_inputvalue=8}`

[image: error]

[Code in Java](https://github.com/yaowen613/ListViewEditTextCheckbox/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/yaowen/listviewedittextcheckbox/ListEditorAdapter.java)

Comment: ...love the red arrow in your screenshot! - Screenshots are generally discouraged, but this one's so appropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem centers around this statement in your question:

```
var mData: List<Map<String, String>>? = null
```

In Kotlin, the `Map` type is immutable, and so has no `.put()` method.  That's the problem you're running up against. To fix it, just change this statement to:

```
var mData: List<MutableMap<String, String>>? = null
```

A second '?' is necessary after `mData?.get(position)` because that statement will return `null` if `mData == null`.  That is, that statement returns a type of `MutableMap<String, String>?` even though the `.put()` by itself would return a type of `MutableMap<String, String>`.

To summarize...if you create a list of mutable maps, the compiler will then be happy with the statement:

```
mData?.get(position)?.put("list_item_inputvalue", s.toString())
```

Comment: It's working perfect now, thanks. `mData?.get(position)?.put("list_item_inputvalue", s.toString())`

Comment: ".get() can return null if given an index that doesn't exist in the list." - that's not true, `get` fails if the index is out of valid indices range.

Comment: @Ilya is correct. Also, the element type is not nullable so `get` can't return null in this case even when the index is in range. The [safe call operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) is necessary here because `mData?.get` will return null if `mData == null`.

Comment: I finally realized just what @Illya was saying, with @Slaw explaining further.  The second `?` is only necessary because of the first `?` and the fact that `mData?.get()` will return null if `mData == null`.  If `mData != null`, `mdata?.get()` will never return null.  I've updated my answer to remove my incorrect statement about `.get()` and added an explanation of just why the second `?` is necessary.  Continue to correct me folks if I still have this wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Initially, it wasn't clear what exactly the question was, so let's start with the various syntax elements in here:

- `!!`: *the not-null assertion operator (!!) converts any value to a non-null type and throws an exception if the value is null. We can write b!!, and this will return a non-null value of b (e.g., a String in our example) or throw an NPE if b is null* (quoted from [kotlinlang](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html))
- `[position]`: *Square brackets are translated to calls to get and set with appropriate numbers of arguments.* (again, from [kotlinlang](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html)) In other words: 
  that is simply "syntactic" sugar: you can treat a collection (probably a list) as an array. Meaning: instead of writing down `get(index)` to denote an element in a list, you can just go `[index]` as if that were an ordinary array.

Kotlin allows to use `someMap[someKey]` for its **own** maps. So, to answer the *initial* question, a further "conversion" could replace the call to `put()` via square brackets as well.

In that case, you have to be aware of the fact that Kotlin maps are immutable by default (so when using `mapOf()` you get a immutable map). Or, if you want to have a mutable Kotlin map "around" a Java map, you have to use `mutableMapOf()`!

Comment: Thanks for your comments to all. Then you can not do put () conversion. The code of this project in java I have taken to implement it in kotlin only that problem I have everything else works perfect for me. I will continue to see another alternative, thanks again for your comments. If someone wants to take a look at the original project in java, this one is: https://github.com/yaowen613/ListViewEditTextCheckbox/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/yaowen/listviewedittextcheckbox/ListEditorAdapter.java

Comment: @Steve My problem is this part of the code `mData?.get(position).put("list_item_inputvalue", s.toString())`does not work for me in kotlin (see image that I attach now in the original post)